# Saltstack master can't find execution module, says not available

Tags: python, salt-stack

I have written a simple module and have put the file under `<salt_file_roots>/_modules`, the content is more or less:

```
# foomod.py
def foo(*args):
    return {'name': 'foo', 'result': True}
```

I've run `salt minion saltutil.sync_all`, have seen the output with the module I added. I can see that it was synced in minion log as well.

```
minion:
    - modules.foomod
```

**1.** I can use it from the minion:

```
$ salt-call foomod.foo
local:
    ----------
    name:
        foo
    result:
        True
```

**2.** I can include it in a state using `module.run` and run the state, and it also works.

**3.** But when I call it from master, this happens:

```
$ salt minion foomod.foo
minion:
    - 'foomod.foo' is not available.
```

I see the call on minion log as well when I call from master

```
2014-07-29 15:30:44,290 [salt.minion      ][INFO    ] User root Executing command foomod.foo with jid 20140729153044256654
2014-07-29 15:30:44,291 [salt.minion      ][DEBUG   ] Command details {'tgt_type': 'glob', 'jid': '20140729153044256654', 'tgt': 'minion', 'ret': '', 'user': 'root', 'arg': [], 'fun': 'foomod.foo'}
2014-07-29 15:30:44,308 [salt.minion      ][INFO    ] Returning information for job: 20140729153044256654
```

So either I skipped the part where I enable this to be run from master directly or I imagined a feature that doesn't exists.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of Salt are you using? The output of

    "salt minion test.versions_report"

and

    "salt-master --versions-report"

would be very helpful.

Comment: This lead me into the right direction, ``pycrypto`` was older on minion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering own question. Salt master had `pycrypto==2.6.1` and minion had `pycrypto==2.4.1`. Updating it on minion solved it.